# How would I prove that each subelement of an element of a powerset appears exactly $2^{n-1}$ times in the powerset?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Basically if given a set $\{a,b,c\}$ how can I prove that $a$ will appear $4$ times, $b$ will appear $4$ times, and $c$ will appear $4$ times through logic (i.e. not bruteforce).

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: A class $C$ consists of $n$ people, including $a$. We want to make a subset of $C$ that includes $a$.  Line up the $n-1$ other kids in a row. Go down the row, and say yes if the kid will accompany $a$, and no if she will not. There are $2^{n-1}$ yes/no patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: If $X$ is your set, and $x\in X$, there is one subset of $X$ containing $x$ for each subset of $X\setminus\{x\}$; do you see why?

A further hint, spoiler-protected:

> If $x\in A\subseteq X$, pair up the sets $A$ and $A\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: So I am not sure how you can make the assumption that there are equal amounts of subsets containing and not containing x. could you point me to the theorem that states that?

Comment: @bobby: That's basically the theorem that you're proving in this problem. The further hint contains the essential idea that you need.